# How to create expandable/retractable form MS Access 2013 VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a data entry form for one of my database tables. For one of the sections, I have the text field with ONLY the caption: "Description 1" showing. If the Description 1 textbox is filled out by the user, I want it to show the Description 2 textbox. If the user fills out the Description 2 textbox, the Description 3 textbox will show up and so on up to 10 Description textboxes. Is there a way to hide the extra text boxes kind of like when you fill out the information while creating a macro? For example when you click Create --> Macro, there is only a dropdown box for you to select an action. If you choose Open Form and hit enter, 6 more text boxes with captions appear.

Is there a way to get that kind of functionality in a form? Also, in the Macro builder, it dynamically rearranges the page for you, can this also be done with the form?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Mark the visible property as false

   [image]
2. Add `OnChange` event for each textbox.

   [image]
3. Write the VBA code to determine if the next control will be showed or hide. Note, the `Me!FormControlItem.Text` is accessible only if the control is focused.

There is the 3 functions for each control.

```
Private Sub text1_Change()
    If Not Trim(Me!text1.Text) = "" Then
        Me!Text2.Visible = True
        Me!Label2.Visible = True
    ElseIf Not Trim(Me!Text2) = "" Then
        Me!Text2.Visible = True
        Me!Label2.Visible = True
    Else
        Me!Text2.Visible = False
        Me!Label2.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Text2_Change()
    If Not Trim(Me!Text2.Text) = "" Then
        Me!Text3.Visible = True
        Me!Label3.Visible = True
    ElseIf Not Trim(Me!Text3) = "" Then
        Me!Text3.Visible = True
        Me!Label3.Visible = True
    Else
        Me!Text3.Visible = False
        Me!Label3.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Text3_Change()
    If Not Trim(Me!Text3.Text) = "" Then
        Me!Text4.Visible = True
        Me!Label4.Visible = True
    ElseIf Not Trim(Me!Text4) = "" Then
        Me!Text4.Visible = True
        Me!Label4.Visible = True
    Else
        Me!Text4.Visible = False
        Me!Label4.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

5. Enjoy!

Comment: When I press enter on Description 1 textbox after typing some words, it shows the Description 2 textbox which is good. However, when I press enter on the Description 1 textbox, whatever words are written is copied to the Description 2 textbox